# If statement with binding value is causing app to crash

Tags: swiftui

I have view parentView, view B and view C.

View parentView is a parent view and contains @State bool value which is being passed into view B and from view B to view C. The view B is inside a if statement and the statement is controlled from view C. However, if I change the value in view C, it causes the app to crash.

Im using iPhone 12 Pro, iOS 16.0.2.

Here is parentView:

```
@main
struct parentView: App {
    @State var isLogged: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Color("F6F6F6").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                if isLogged == false {
                    ViewA(isLogged: $isLogged)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is view B:

```
 struct ViewB: View {
        var isLogged: Binding<Bool>
        @State private var loginNavigationIsActive = false
        
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    Button("GO") {
                        loginNavigationIsActive = true
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        "",
                        destination: ViewC(isLogged: isLogged, loginNavigationIsActive: $loginNavigationIsActive),
                        isActive: $loginNavigationIsActive
                    )
                    .hidden()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is view C:

```
 struct ViewC: View {
        var isLogged: Binding<Bool>
        var loginNavigationIsActive: Binding<Bool>
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                    Button("BACK") {
                        isLogged.wrappedValue = true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `@Binding var isLogged: Bool` instead of `var isLogged: Binding<Bool>`.

Comment: You also only need 1 NavigationView but if you are supporting iOS 16+ you should use 1 NavigationStack. I suggest looking at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials.

Comment: what is `ViewA`? and how do you get to `ViewB` from `ViewA`? What error do you get and on which line of the code?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't shared your buildable code (ViewA is missing), I am sharing some suggestions to answer your question:

1. Use `@Binding` instead of `Binding<Bool>`.
2. Properly handle navigation with `NavigationStack` and `navigationDestination` to handle navigation (This is out of your question). The version of `NavigationLink` you are using is deprecated.
3. I see that in all of your view you need `isLogged` value. Consider wrapping inside an class object and inject as `@EnvironmentObject` so that you don't have to pass as argument in all of the views.